Can 2,4-dimethylcyclohexa-2,5-dien-1-one exhibit tautomerism
Can the compound 2,4-dimethylcyclohexa-2,5-dien-1-one exhibit tautomerism? I think it does exhibit tautomerism because of availability of hydrogen on the 4th carbon (numbered according to IUPAC). But it is given in a book that the compound doesn't exhibit tautomerism. Can anyone explain why?


Of course it does. It is the 2,6-dimethyl thing that does not. This, I believe, was the intent of the book's statement, and 4,6 is a misprint.

Yeah.But they gave bond line structure.I wrote the IUPAC name.

This makes the misprint less probable. The rest of what I said still stands.

@IvanNeretin what prevents the 2,6 compound from tautomerizig? I would think the process is independent of where you put the substituents in the (ph)enolic form.

@OscarLanzi It has no alpha hydrogen to jump on the O and make it an OH.

...unless the $\gamma$ hydrogens were to do so in an intermolecular process. You'd actually have a $\gamma$ hydrogen moving even from the ketonic tautomer shown in the question.

If the book has actually specified that it doesn't tautomerize, then the only reason I can think of is that even if the compound tautomerizes, the concentration of initial compound is more than the tautomer during equilibrium (due to weaker acid and base groups present). It might be that keto content is so high as compared to enolic content, that it is neglected, though we should not count it as not present at all.
It should be better if you attach the reference of the book or a picture of it to get the context of the information provided.

It is a question in a problems workbook and no explanation or solution is given in that
